# PHP nested if using $_GET

Tags: php

Trying to use a $_GET within a $_GET
It's not throwing any errors but isn't working the way I want it to. It's been a while since I've done this so I don't know if I'm overlooking something or not. I'm trying to be able to do something like index.php?chatroom&id=1

```
$pgtitle = '';
$cractive = '';
$dactive = '';
$acactive = '';
$pgChat = '';
if(isset($_GET['chatroom'])){
    $cractive = 'active';
    if (isset($_GET['cid']) == "1") {
        $pgChat == 'Global Chatroom';
    }else if(isset($_GET['cid']) == "2"){
        $pgChat == 'AK Chatroom';
    }else if(isset($_GET['cid']) == "3"){
        $pgChat == 'AZ Chatroom';
    } else {
        echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; URL=index.php?chatroom&cid=1">';
    }
}else{
    header('Location: index.php?dashboard');
}
```

Comment: `isset($_GET['cid'])` just returns if the key is set, not what the value is. `isset($_GET['cid']) == "1"` will always return true if it exists, which it does not. You're passing `id` in the Url, but checking for `cid`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PHP - Nested If Statements Issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5086028/php-nested-if-statements-issue)

Comment: Test if the variable is set first and report an error if it isn't. Then test the value separately.

Answer (score 2):

`isset()` returns a boolean not the content of the variable, and you was using `==` instead of `=` in `$pgChat == 'Global Chatroom';`, here is an example using your code for something like `index.php?chatroom&cid=1`:

```php
if (isset($_GET['chatroom'])) {
    $cractive = 'active';

    if (isset($_GET['cid'])) {
        if ($_GET['cid'] == "1") {
            $pgChat = 'Global Chatroom';
        } elseif ($_GET['cid'] == "2") {
            $pgChat = 'AK Chatroom';
        } elseif ($_GET['cid'] == "3") {
            $pgChat = 'AZ Chatroom';
        } else {
            echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; URL=index.php?chatroom&cid=1">';
        }
    } else {
        echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; URL=index.php?chatroom&cid=1">';
    }
}
```

---

EXTRA: You can do the same thing in that way if you wanna.

```php
$chats = [
    '1' => 'Global Chatroom',
    '2' => 'AK Chatroom',
    '3' => 'AZ Chatroom',
];

if (isset($_GET['chatroom'])) {
    $cractive = 'active';

    if (isset($_GET['cid']) && isset($chats[$_GET['cid']])) {
        $pgChat = $chats[$_GET['cid']];
    } else {
        echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; URL=index.php?chatroom&cid=1">';
    }
}
```